# Remove Aloha-Editor Blue Focus Outline

Tags: aloha-editor

I'm very new to Aloha (WYSIWYG) Editor and i would like to know how to remove/disable its blue outline then the editing field is on focus.

I've managed to disable the yellow highlight outlines, but couldn't find a way to disable the blue on focus border outline.

Any friendly advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you positive this outline is caused by Aloha? I am using Aloha and I do not have any. Perhaps you use some additional CSS other than the editor's adding an outline to input with focus. Can you show the example? Some jsfiddle?

Comment: hi @marcin, this blue border only shows up when i added aloha to my project, and it only appears then the textarea field is on focus :-/ i'm using it with bootstrap. going to test it with an empty project (without other css styles) and i'll give you feedback

Comment: hi again, the blue border has nothing to do with bootstrap. i've uploaded an example so that you can see for yourself: http://goo.gl/FbmQOy looking forward for some feedback, tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blue outline is made by the "highlighteditables" plugin's CSS `src/plugins/common/highlighteditables/css/highlighteditables.css`:

```
.aloha-editable-active, .aloha-editable-active[contenteditable=true]:focus {
    outline: #80B5F2 solid 5px !important;
}
```

Check that when running the inspector in the web browser, selecting the element and disabling this style helps.

Note the ugly programming style with `!important` :(

Unfortunately, as you can can choose plugins to load you only choose JavaScript, CSS of all the plugins enabled during the build are merged into the `aloha.css` and are always loaded.

One way to fix it is to build the editor yourself. Basic introduction is described in section "4.3 Customized Builds" of [Develop Aloha Editor guide](http://www.aloha-editor.org/guides/develop_aloha.html).

As building Aloha yourself requires some effort, you may be interested in quick workaround using the inline style:

```
outline: none !important;
```

for the element you have problem with. Note the `!important` keyword - it is required.

Comment: hi @marcin, thanks for your feedback. i've managed to resolve this issue with your suggestion :) once again, thanks allot!